# QtCreator can't even build empty project - The following error occurred while executing this line

Tags: android, c++, qt, ant, qt-creator

I get some very unhelpful errors from Qt creator, which I have just installed using [tutorial on Qt website](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html).

```
-dex:
      [dex] input: D:\techsys\build-androidtest-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_1-Debug\android-build\bin\classes
      [dex] input: D:\techsys\build-androidtest-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_1-Debug\android-build\libs\QtAndroid-bundled.jar
      [dex] input: D:\techsys\build-androidtest-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_1-Debug\android-build\libs\QtAndroidAccessibility-bundled.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing D:\techsys\build-androidtest-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_1-Debug\android-build\libs\QtAndroid-bundled.jar -> QtAndroid-bundled-15710ac48ee3b8e0790e2c0724eced85.jar
       [dx] Error occurred during initialization of VM
       [dx] Could not reserve enough space for object heap
       [dx] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
       [dx] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\mareda\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:888: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\mareda\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:890: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\mareda\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:902: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\mareda\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:283: null returned: 1

Total time: 1 second
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
11:50:50: The process "C:\Qt\android.5.5.1\5.5\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project androidtest (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.5.1))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
11:50:50: Elapsed time: 00:05.
```

I don't really get what does it mean. This is my configuration:

[image: image description]

I also tried selecting *Use Gradle instead of Ant*. it didn't affect anything. What expecially freaks me out is the awkward error: `The following error occurred while executing this line:` without mentioning any actual error.

Comment: What do you get when you checkmark "Use Gradle" in the "**Build Android APK**" step under **Build Steps** in the Projects tab, and try building?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to fix it:

```
Go to Start->Control Panel->System->Advanced(tab)->Environment Variables->System Variables->New:
Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable value: -Xmx512M



Variable name: Path
Variable value: ;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;F:\JDK\bin;
Change this to your appropriate path.
```

Comment: But I want to change the setting only for Qt creator, not whole operating system!

Comment: Before giving -1 , read this. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap-resolved.88119/

Comment: Ok, after reading the thread I realised I must also restart the IDE. Still, this is more like ad-hoc solution, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem related with memory. You must have enough RAM on system. If not then please add large swap. This would allow dx to complete build and not die in middle. I was facing this issue on small VPS node. Now its fixed.